# Facebook Wall Post Picture relative URL PhoneGap

Tags: facebook, api, cordova, post, image

I would like to post to facebook wall with a local picture in a Phone Gap Project.
Here is the code.

```
function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

In the line:

```
picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
```

I tried to change it into a relative url like:

```
picture: '../blabla.png',
```

and I continue getting the error of API ERROR Code 100, Picture URL is not correctly formatted. I checked the facebook api and it is not clearly stated there. It says:

The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: iirc, the picture need to be accessible on the internet. Thus, you cannot use local images.

Comment: The image url must be an Absolute URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iirc, the picture need to be accessible on the internet. Thus, you cannot use local images. – wmfairuz

The image url must be an Absolute URL – Tommy Crush

Problem solved.